# Add an image behind a video file (.mp4) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am attempting to add an image behind a video using moviepy and cannot come up with any way to do it. My image dimension is (1080 x 720) and my video dimension is (200 x 200). I am trying to put the video file on top of the image file, place it in the midlle and export the final video with the dimensions of the image. This is a visual representation of what I am trying to achieve:

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRMYJ.png)

I tried doing this with the following code, but could not manage to get it to work. Any help is seriously appreciated :)

```
import moviepy
import moviepy.editor as mp

video = mp.VideoFileClip("/media/pi/vid.mp4")

logo = (mp.ImageClip("/media/pi/pic.png"))

# Preferably I would want the image to be the same duration as the video file. 
# The following was just for testing.
final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([video, logo.set_duration(3)])
final.write_videofile("test.mp4")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hello!

I can't test it now, but [here](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/compositing.html#id1) it said that

> *Note that by default the composition has the size of its first clip (as it is generally a background)*

So maybe you should try this (if you don't know, what is "center", you should see [docs](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/compositing.html#positioning-clips)):

```
import moviepy
import moviepy.editor as mp

video = mp.VideoFileClip("/media/pi/vid.mp4")
logo = (mp.ImageClip("/media/pi/pic.png"))

final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([logo, video.set_position("center")])
final.write_videofile("test.mp4")
```

SIDE NOTE: you should downgrade from moviepy 1.0.1 to moviepy 1.0.0, otherwise you will get an "object has no attribute stdout" error or something like that. To downgrade:

```
pip install moviepy==1.0.0
```

or

```
 pip3 install moviepy = 1.0.0
```